# Using R to create a choropleth generated from lat/lon lists - with data generated internally

Tags: r, sp, ggplot2, ggmap

a friend referred me here as opposed to the regular Stack Overflow site, as this community maybe better able to help!

My issue is largely with the syntax and framework of `ggmap`,`ggplot`, and the `sp` package.

I have already summarised and prepped my data. [This link](https://gist.github.com/wotarpelo/91bf2f6c0703820b6b7a981ec057f33d) shows (some of) the data I'm trying to map. I used the following code block to create Spatial polygon objects instead of lists of lat/long values, as shown in the data in the above link:

```
createShape = function(sub){
  #This funciton takes the list of lat/lng values and returns a SHAPE which should be plottable on ggmap/ggplot
  tempData = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, as.list(VICshapes[which(VICshapes$Suburb==sub),] %>% select(coords))[[1]][[1]]))
  names(tempData) = c('lat', 'lng')
  p = Polygon(tempData)
  ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
  sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
  return(sps)
}
VICshapes[['shape']] = lapply(suburbNames, function(x) createShape(x))
```

So - I've got the data I want to plot. I've got shapes. I've got the packages installed... but how do I actually make things look pretty and presentable? ANY of the help on packages seems to assume I have .shp files, along with other external data which defines how I plot it all. Apparently I need to use `ggmap::fortify()` or `broom::tidy` on the shape files to get them to plot. Then I just get warnings from `ggmap` and `ggplot` about the length of aes arguments being incorrect.

I'm genuinely not sure how to proceed with this, but I know I have the necessary data to show what I want to show - I just don't know how to move forward.

Using R's inbuilt `plot` function on the output of the `createShape()` function above shows me a shape as I want. Great - but what if I want ALL the shapes, then coloured according to another variable - which is linked by a common key?

At this stage I'm so frustrated with it all - I'll literally pay someone's rent for a month if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to end up with is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, which is like a regular data frame but there's some geometry for each row. This is what you get when you read a shapefile using `readOGR`, `raster::shapefile`, or `readSHPpoly` functions.

Your `createShape()` function returns a length-one vector of `SpatialPolygons` objects, then your `lapply` is returning a list of those. If you `rbind` to combine them you should get a longer vector of SpatialPolygons objects:

```
SpP = do.call(rbind, lapply(suburbNames, function(x) createShape(x)))
```

This should print out something like this depending on your data:

```
> SpP
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 100 
extent      : 0.5, 10.5, 0.5, 10.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA
```

To make a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, we use the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` function with a data frame argument:

```
> d = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
          SpP,
          data=data.frame(foo=1:length(SpP)),
          match.ID = FALSE)
```

`d` is now a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with 100 features (spatial regions) and one data column, `foo`:

```
> d
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 100 
extent      : 0.5, 10.5, 0.5, 10.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : foo 
min values  :   1 
max values  : 100
```

and you can make a quick map this way:

```
> spplot(d,"foo")
>
```

To add extra columns to `d`, treat it like a data frame, and its order is the same order as the `SpatialPolygons` that constructed it.

The help pages for the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class give a reproducible example of creating an SPDF from scratch. Run:

```
  help("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class")
```

Its worth noting that the `sp` class and its data formats have been mostly superseded by the `sf` package and *its* data formats - the principles are the same though - a data frame with a geometry for each row.

Lucky for you I own my house so that rent payment will be zero :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I'm headed in the right direction - albeit now I've come across an issue with ID's for the spatial polygons, namely `invalid class “SpatialPolygons” object: non-unique Polygons ID slot values`

If I am creating another df to map with surely the IDs should be the rows on which the polygons are created to begin with - namely the `$Suburb` variable? That's what's common across all of the data I'm using.

Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: You are creating all your Polygons with ID=1: `ps = Polygons(list(p),1)` - your code at that point doesn't have a row number to make into an ID. You could refactor or use a random integer - `runif(1, 1, 1e12)` should make collisions unlikely. I used `match.ID=FALSE` so the SpatialPolygons and data frame are matched by order and not rearranged.

Comment: Aha!! I should've caught that. I'm now just using the suburb as the id - which I'm passing to that method anyway. Seems like there's some redundant data storage there, but so be it. Making progress, thanks!